# How do I access parameters (non-url and url) in ui-router from the state component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out working with ui-router and React and have gotten stuck when accessing state params from the state component. ui-router has plenty of documentation on how to create the states, routes, params etc. but almost none that I have found on how to actually access them. The routing and transitions are working, but need to know how to use the params I pass in order to proceed. Thanks for any help!

Router setup and where homeState is declared with params

```
const router = new UIRouterReact()
router.plugin(servicesPlugin)
router.plugin(pushStateLocationPlugin)

var loginState = {
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    component: LoginPage
}

var homeState = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    component: HomePage,
    params: { 
        id: {
            type: "int",
            array: false
        }
    }
}

var registerState = {
    name: 'register',
    url: '/register',
    component: () => <h2>Register me!</h2>
}

var loginHelpState = {
    name: 'loginHelp',
    url: '/login-help',
    component: () => <h2>Reset my password!</h2>
}

const states = [loginState, homeState, registerState, loginHelpState]

states.forEach(state => router.stateRegistry.register(state))
```

Inside my login state, I call the below line on successful login. Will eventually pass more user details, but for now just testing with sending user id (stored in resp.id). The routing works and the app transitions to the 'home' component, but cant figure out how to access the id from there.

```
router.stateService.go('home', {id: resp.id})
```

My home state component

```
import React from 'react'
import './homePage.css'

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="homepage">
      <div className="header">Header</div>
      <div className="asset-summary">Asset Summary</div>
      <div className="family-summary">Family Summary</div>
      <div className="backlog-summary">Backlog Summary</div>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have solved this. Posting my solution in case anyone else has this problem.

I changed the route state declaration, adding in a resolve--->

```
var homeState = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    component: HomePage,
    params: {
        id: {
            type: "int",
            array: false
        }
    },
    resolve: [
        {
            token: 'id',
            deps: ['$transition$'],
            resolveFn: (trans) => {
                const id = trans.params().id
                return id
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And then I could access the param through props in my functional component

```
function HomePage(props) {
    const id = props.id

    return (
        <div className="homepage">
            <div className="header">Header ID:{id}</div>
            <div className="asset-summary">Asset Summary</div>
            <div className="family-summary">Family Summary</div>
            <div className="backlog-summary">Backlog Summary</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Pretty simple in the end, but banged my head against the confusing layout of docs and their tendency to jump to Angular instructions instead of React. Hope this helps someone.